# How can I auto-resize an image to fit a 'view/flex-box' container in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to show any sized image data in resized image container in react native. The problem that I am facing is in resizing the image container. I have tested the contain, stretched, and cover resizes modes but I am not getting the required results. When I use contain mode the image is showing extra paddings around it, with the stretched mode, the image is stretching and compressing and with the cover mode, the image is cutting. Tried to fix with react-native-canvas, react-native-FitToImage, react-native-scale-image, react-native-image-view but getting same result while using resize mode in Image component.[I want to reduce container size equal to image size click on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZMDi.jpg) and here is my code given below

```
             <ViewShot
                  ref={viewShotRef}
                  style={
                    {flex: 1 / 1.1,}
                  }
                  options={{format: 'jpg', quality: 1.0, result: 'base64'}}>
                  <Image
                    source={{
                      uri:
                        'data:image/jpeg;base64,' +
                        props.background_remove.image,
                    }}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={
                      {
                        flex: 1
                      }
                    }
                  />
                </ViewShot>
```

Comment: why is your resizeMode="contain" outside style?

Comment: If I am using resizeMode inside the style then also getting the same result.

Comment: remove the flex 1 in the image, flex should be on the container view or whichever you are using

Comment: not resolved image not displayed if I remove flex or height, width

Comment: do you have screenshot of how the image size looks like?

Comment: yes please check it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZMDi.jpg

Comment: so what you want to achieve is to fit the image to the entire view regardless of the size of the actual image?

Comment: i want to fit the view size equal to actual image because if i stretch the image then image fit in the view container but image view is to bad.

Comment: I updated my answer below with sample size for viewShot similar to image

Comment: Any body can help me?

Answer (score 0):

For example I have a letter size viewShot with image:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
 <ViewShot
  ref={viewShotRef}
  options={{
   format: "jpg",
   width: 2550,
   height: 3300,
   quality: 1,
   result: 'base64'
  }}
   style={{
    width: 2550,
    height: 3300,
    overflow: 'hidden'
   }}
 >

  <View style={{zIndex: 3}}>
    <Image
     source={{
     uri:
      'data:image/jpeg;base64,' +
       props.background_remove.image,
     }}
 
     style={{
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      width: 2550,
      height: 3300
     }}
   />
 </ViewShot>
</View>
```

Comment: not fixed, getting the same result as mentioned previously